# click_button on a button that was initially disabled, but enabled using javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I have a test that keeps failing because the button is initially disabled until I check a checkbox which then removes the disabled attribute from the button.

```
%button.btn.btn-success{id: 'registration_button', :type => "submit", :disabled=>'disabled'} Register

$('#tos_acceptance').click ->
  tosChecked = $('#tos_acceptance').is(':checked');
if tosChecked
  $('#registration_button').attr('disabled', false);
else
  $('#registration_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

The problem I keep getting is that capybara cannot find the button.

```
 Unable to find button "Register" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

This is part of my test:

```
When(/^User goes to the registration page and enters (.*) and (.*) and (.*)$/) do  |email, password, password_confirmation|
  within all('.nav')[1] do
     click_link('Register')
   end
   current_path.should == new_user_registration_path
   page.should have_content('Please create your new account')
   fill_in('user[email]', :with => email)
   fill_in('user[password]', :with => password)
   fill_in('user[password_confirmation]', :with => password_confirmation)
   check 'tos_acceptance'
   click_button('Register')
end
```

Here is my related Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false   
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'launchy'                  
  gem 'autotest'
  gem 'turn', :require => false  
  gem 'minitest', '=4.7.5'               
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '>= 0.14.23'
```

How do I enable the button (with the javascript logic) so that this test passes? If I remove the disabled attribute, my tests pass fine, so I'm pretty confident that the issue is with enabling JS for the cucumber tests.

Comment: What capybara driver are you using? Did you mark your test with 'js: true'?

Comment: @ivalkeen I'm not sure what you mean by capybara driver, but I've included my Gemfile. Maybe I need something like selenium or webkit?

Comment: And please provide full spec example too. Including `describe` and `it `. It seems to me you didn't enable javascript for your capybara specs, that's why javascript is not executed during spec run and thus button is not enabled.

Comment: Do you have `@javascript` before your scenario?

Comment: @ivalkeen No, that was the issue. Can you please submit the answer so that I can accept it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it seems, you didn't enable javascript for your Cucumber scenario.

You should add `@javascript` before your `scenario` to enable javascript for this scenario (`selenium` web driver will be used by default): https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-cucumber

If you don't want to use selenium and want to enable headless javascript driver (like capybara-webkit or poltergeist), you'll need to add a gem to your Gemfile and change javascript driver as described here: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's not actually disabled-- so I don't think the issue is Capybara-- at least that's my guess-- You have to actually remove the disabled attribute. This doesn't address the test-- but in my experience the disabled attribute must actually be removed from the DOM to make the button disabled.

```
$('#tos_acceptance').click ->
  tosChecked = $('#tos_acceptance').is(':checked');
if tosChecked
  $('#registration_button').removeAttr('disabled');
else
  $('#registration_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: I don't think this is the case. When I manually tested my previous code, the button was being enabled when I checked the checkbox. I tried changing my JS code to this snippet, but it did not work.